# Can Node.js stream be made as coroutine?

Tags: node.js, generator, coroutine

Is there a way to make Node.js stream as coroutine.

Example
a Fibonacci numbers stream.

```
fibonacci.on('data', cb);
//The callback (cb) is like
function cb(data)
{
    //something done with data here ...
}
```

Expectation

```
function* fibonacciGenerator()
{
    fibonacci.on('data', cb);
    //Don't know what has to be done further... 
};

var fibGen = fibonacciGenerator();
fibGen.next().value(cb);
fibGen.next().value(cb);
fibGen.next().value(cb);
.
.
.
```

Take desired numbers from the generator. Here Fibonacci number series is just an example, in reality the stream could be of anything a file, mongodb query result, etc.

Maybe something like this

1. Make the 'stream.on' function as a generator.
2. Place yield inside the callback function.
3. Obtain generator object.
4. Call next and take the next value in stream.

Is it at-least possible if yes how and if not why? Maybe a dumb question :)

Comment: well, no. you can't do it. you have to wait until async/await will be standardized.

Comment: it is possible in python...  

`def sgen(filename):  
 f = open(filename,'r')  
 for l in f:  
  yield f.readline()  
  
g = sgen('/home/datadumpfile.xml')  
  
print(next(g))  
print(next(g))  
print(next(g))`

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use a transpiler (e.g. Babel) or wait until `async`/`await` make it to Node.js, you can implement it yourself using generators and promises.

The downside is that your code must live inside a generator.

---

---

First, you can make a helper that receives a stream and returns a function that, when called, returns a promise for the next "event" of the stream (e.g. `data`).

```
function streamToPromises(stream) {
  return function() {
    if (stream.isPaused()) {
      stream.resume();
    }

    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      stream.once('data', function() {
        resolve.apply(stream, arguments);
        stream.pause();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

It pauses the stream when you're not using it, and resumes it when you ask it the next value.

---

Next, you have a helper that receives a generator as an argument, and every time it yields a promise, it resolves it and passes its result back to the generator.

```
function run(fn) {
  var gen = fn();
  var promise = gen.next().value;

  var tick = function() {
    promise.then(function() {
      promise = gen.next.apply(gen, arguments).value;
    }).catch(function(err) {
      // TODO: Handle error.
    }).then(function() {
      tick();
    });
  }

  tick();
}
```

---

Finally, you would do your own logic inside a generator, and run it with the `run` helper, like this:

```
run(function*() {
  var nextFib = streamToPromises(fibonacci);

  var n;

  n = yield nextFib();
  console.log(n);

  n = yield nextFib();
  console.log(n);
});
```

- Your own generator will yield promises, pausing its execution and passing the control to the `run` function.
- The `run` function will resolve the promise and pass its value back to your own generator.

---

That's the gist of it. You'd need to modify `streamToPromises` to check for other events as well (e.g. `end` or `error`).

Answer (score 1):

```
class FibonacciGeneratorReader extends Readable {
    _isDone = false;
    _fibCount = null;
    _gen = function *() {
        let prev = 0, curr = 1, count = 1;
        while (this._fibCount === -1 || count++ < this._fibCount) {
            yield curr;
            [prev, curr] = [curr, prev + curr];
        }
        return curr;
    }.bind(this)();

    constructor(fibCount) {
        super({
            objectMode: true,
            read: size => {
                if (this._isDone) {
                    this.push(null);
                } else {
                    let fib = this._gen.next();
                    this._isDone = fib.done;
                    this.push(fib.value.toString() + '\n');
                }
            }
        });

        this._fibCount = fibCount || -1;
    }
}

new FibonacciGeneratorReader(10).pipe(process.stdout);
```

### Output should be:

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
```